# How to get .NET 5 symbols to show up in the call stack in Process Hacker or Process Explorer?

Tags: debugging, .net-core, .net-5, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I created a simple console application in both .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 5 (same code in both), but symbols resolve differently across various debugging tools.

If I run both applications, launch Process Hacker, open the process's properties, click on the Threads tab, and open the Stack for the primary managed thread, the .NET 4.8 Stack shows resolved symbols for my classes and methods, but the .NET 5 Stack does not -- it shows hex strings like `0x7ffbac6087a3`.

In both cases, calls to `System.Console.dll!System.Console.ReadKey()` resolve correctly, so I know I have my symbol loading configured correctly (`_NT_SYMBOL_PATH = "srv*C:\Source\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols"`).  In both cases, the projects are configured for full debug type and to include debug symbols.  In both cases, there is a .pdb to go along with the .exe.

Sysinternals Process Explorer won't display any of that - the bottom of the call stack is 0x0.

If I take a dump of the applications, I can load them into WinDbg Preview and am able to see all of  my code as expected.  For the .NET 5 application, the normal Stack shows the same thing as Process Hacker (e.g. `0x7ffbac6087a3`), but if I run the command `!CLRStack -a`, those hex values get properly resolved (e.g. `000000BD4F17E840 00007ffbac6087a3 SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.Program.Run() [C:\Source\research\SymbolsCore\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp\Program.cs @ 18]`).

So, there's the background.  Here are the questions:

1.) Why doesn't the Process Hacker Stack resolve symbols for my classes in a .NET 5 application, but it does for the exact same code in a .NET Framework 4.8 application?

2.) Why doesn't Sysinternals Process Explorer display any of my code (just 0x0) for either application?  In case it matters, I run `procexp64.exe` and my machine is x64 Windows 10 Enterprise.  If I run 'procexp.exe`, it ultimately launches the x64 version anyhow.  Mentioning this in case there is an issue with 32 vs. 64 bit.

3.) Both Process Hacker and Process Explorer have process tabs specifically for .NET (e.g. .NET assemblies and .NET performance), and those tabs only show up for the .NET Framework 4.8 application, but not for the .NET 5 application.  Is this by-design or do I have something configured wrong?

4.) In WinDbg Preview, is this behavior by-design?  If so, why?

5.) Are there other special things to consider when debugging/analyzing .NET 5/Core applications outside of Visual Studio?

That's a lot of questions, but they're all closely related, and I suspect there may be some fundamental thing(s) that I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 20210803 10:55 AM CDT
Per [magicandre1981](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466046/magicandre1981)'s comment, I installed the nightly of Process Hacker (v3.0.4234).

- It still doesn't resolve those symbols.
- It does show .NET assemblies and .NET performance tabs for the .NET 5 application now, but there are no values on the .NET performance tab.

EDIT: 20210803 05:05 PM CDT
I ran symchk and dumpbin against both of the applications in case this will help anyone diagnose the problem.

.NET 5

```
net5.0> $> pwd
C:\Source\research\SymbolsCore\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp\bin\Debug\net5.0

net5.0> $> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\symchk.exe' .\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.exe /r

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 0
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 1


net5.0> $> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\Hostx64\x64\dumpbin.exe' /PDBPATH:VERBOSE .\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.29.30040.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file .\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
  PDB file 'C:\Source\research\SymbolsCore\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp\bin\Debug\net5.0\apphost.pdb' checked.  (File not found)
  PDB file 'D:\workspace\_work\1\s\artifacts\obj\win-x64.Release\corehost\cli\apphost\standalone\Release\apphost.pdb' checked.  (File not found)
  PDB file 'C:\WINDOWS\symbols\exe\apphost.pdb' checked.  (File not found)
  PDB file 'C:\WINDOWS\exe\apphost.pdb' checked.  (File not found)
  PDB file 'C:\WINDOWS\apphost.pdb' checked.  (File not found)

  Summary

        2000 .data
        2000 .pdata
        9000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       14000 .text
        1000 _RDATA


net5.0> $> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\symchk.exe' .\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.dll /r
SYMCHK: SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.dll FAILED  - SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.pdb mismatched or not found
SYMCHK: SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.dll FAILED  - No CodeView information found.

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 2
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 0


net5.0> $> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\Hostx64\x64\dumpbin.exe' /PDBPATH:VERBOSE .\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.29.30040.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file .\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.dll

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
  PDB file found at 'C:\Source\research\SymbolsCore\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp\bin\Debug\net5.0\SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.pdb'

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        2000 .text
```

.NET 4.8

```
Debug> $> pwd
C:\Source\research\SymbolsFramework\SymbolsFrameworkConsoleApp\bin\Debug


Debug> $> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\symchk.exe' .\SymbolsFrameworkConsoleApp.exe /r
SYMCHK: SymbolsFrameworkConsoleApp.exe FAILED  - SymbolsFrameworkConsoleApp.pdb mismatched or not found

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 1
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 0


Debug> $> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\Hostx64\x64\dumpbin.exe' /PDBPATH:VERBOSE .\SymbolsFrameworkConsoleApp.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.29.30040.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file .\SymbolsFrameworkConsoleApp.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
  PDB file found at 'C:\Source\research\SymbolsFramework\SymbolsFrameworkConsoleApp\bin\Debug\SymbolsFrameworkConsoleApp.pdb'

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        2000 .text
```

EDIT: 20210803 07:54 PM CDT

Per [hanpassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s comment, here is the project file (it already had the DebugType set to full).

SymbolsCoreConsoleApp.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

        <PropertyGroup>
                <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
                <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
                <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
                <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
                <DebugType>full</DebugType>
                <Optimize>false</Optimize>
                <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

EDIT: 20210803 08:40 PM CDT

Here are a few screenshots in case it wasn't clear from my explanation.

Notice the `0x7xfbb03a8` addresses instead of resolved symbols.
[image: Process Hacker - Thread Stack - .NET 5]

Notice the resolved symbols for `SymbolsFramework.ConsoleApp.Program` instead of the unresolved `0x7xfbb03a8` addresses.
[image: Process Hacker - Thread Stack - .NET 4.8]

Notice the `0x0` address instead of any resolved symbols.
[image: Process Explorer - Thread Stack - .NET 5]

The .NET Assemblies tab shows up for .NET 5 and appears to populate correctly.
[image: Process Hacker - .NET Assemblies - .NET 5]

The .NET Performance tab shows up for .NET 5, but it has no values.
[image: Process Hacker - .NET Performance - .NET 5]

Comment: have you tried the [nightly of ProcessHacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/nightly.php)?

Comment: No, but I will today.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll post back with the outcome.

Comment: WinDbg is so commonly used, so Microsoft fully embeds the logic to locate the symbol files (both PDB and portable PDB files, from either Microsoft symbol server or from the NuGet package cache). Other tool vendors might be able to replicate the same, but probably they don't yet.

Comment: Lix Li - Process Hacker can locate symbol files (resolves correctly for .NET 4.8).  Are you saying that a tool like Process Hacker Needs to implement different logic for loading PDB files associated with a .NET 5 application than it does for a .NET 4.8 application?

Comment: Edit the project file and add `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>`.  This selects the legacy PDB format that these kind of tools are used to seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Hans!  Appreciate you taking the time.  I edited my question to include the contents of the project file.  I already had the DebugType set to full.

Answer (score 1):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/issues/943) with Process Hacker on GitHub and it was closed a few days back with a fix in the nightly build.  I confirmed that it now works as expected.